# Remove row in document one if cell is dupliicate in other document

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a document with adresses in column C. And another document with adresses in column D. I want to check if any adresses in the first document exists in the other one, and if theres a duplicate that entire row should be deleted. How can I manage this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have to try to do this? What you want, VBA, Formulas?

Comment: Just the most simple solution to the issue please. Is there no macro in excel for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this:

Cols as expected

Sheet: A

```
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Address Sht A |          |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 01        | Add 01   | =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,B!A:A,1,FALSE),"No   Exist") |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 18        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 13        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 18        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 05        | Add 05   |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 13        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 07        | Add 07   |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 08        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 13        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 18        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 11        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 18        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 13        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 14        | Add 14   |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 18        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 13        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 17        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 18        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 18        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Add 20        | No Exist |                                                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Sheet B:

```
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Address Sht B |          |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 01        | Add 01   | =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,A!A:A,1,FALSE),"No Exist") |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 02        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 03        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 04        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 05        | Add 05   |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 02        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 07        | Add 07   |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 02        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 04        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 10        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 02        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 12        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 04        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 14        | Add 14   |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 04        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Add 16        | No Exist |                                                |
+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Whit the formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,A!A:A,1,FALSE),"No Exist")` you can check if the address exist in the other sheet.

Check [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) formulas.